# For loop into numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm just beginning to learn how to use numpy. I have this block of code and am looking to use numpy arrays to represent it. Any tips on how to go about doing so?

```
import numpy as np
for i in range(np):
  direction = random.randint(1, 4)
  if direction == NORTH:
    ypositions[i] += 1
  elif direction == SOUTH:
    ypositions[i] -= 1
  elif direction == EAST:
    xpositions[i] += 1
  elif direction == WEST:
    xpositions[i] -= 1
```

Comment: Represent what exactly?

Comment: `for i in range(np):` is well off the mark. That's the module name. What are you expecting to iterate through here?

Answer (score 1):

With numpy you need to think in terms of whole arrays. So, applying directional deltas based on some random number would need to operate on all coordinates at once.

for example (assuming xpositions and ypositions are numpy arrays):

```
directions = np.random.randint(1,4,25)
ypositions += directions == NORTH
ypositions -= directions == SOUTH
xpositions += directions == EAST
xpositions -= directions == WEST
```

Comment: And of `for i in range(np):`? It's completely impossible to know what the OP intends to iterate.

Comment: ... I'm not the OP. But this _can't_ answer the question if that isn't addressed.

Comment: I had to assume that it was meant to be the range of entries in the xpositions and ypositions arrays. But I agree `range(np)` makes no sense otherwise

Comment: Alain T is correct. I meant it to be the range of entries in the xpositions and positions arrays. I've worked with arrays before in java but not in python (with numpy). I appreciate the help and patience you all have showed me about this question!

Comment: Well, if I let myself be stumped by every little mistake, I'd be asking questions not answering them. You're welcome.